# How would I style a column's elements based on another column's elements in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, background-color

Say, for example, I have a pandas data frame like so:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Greek letters': ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Omega", "Delta"],
    'English letters': ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    'Greek Letter score': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
    'English Letter score': [3, 11, 12, 18, 25]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I want to do is apply specific background colors only to the elements in the columns `Greek letters` and `English letters` based on their respective scores (so, based on the elements in the `Greek Letter score` and `English Letter score` columns respectively).

```
def highlight_letter(value):
    # How would I use the letter element to obtain its corresponding score?
    # score = some technique to obtain the letter's score 
    if score <= 10:
        return 'background-color: lightgreen'
    elif score <= 20:
        return 'background-color: yellow'
    else:
        return 'background-color: blue'

styled_df = df.style.applymap(highlight_letter, subset=['Greek letters', 'English letters'])
```

This is what the expected output should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you need is not `applymap` but `apply` along the rows. To avoid hardcoding, let's assume that you have at least pairs like *"Something letters"* and *"Something Letter score"* in whatever case and column order it can be. With that in mind, I'd suggest this approach:

```py
def highlight_letter(record):
    formatting = record.copy()
    subset = record.index.str.endswith('letters')
    formatting[~subset] = ''
    for name in formatting.index[subset]:
        score = record[name[:-1] + ' score']   # -1 to drop ending s in letters
        formatting[name] = (
            'background-color: lightgreen' if score <= 10 else
            'background-color: yellow' if score <= 20 else
            'background-color: blue'
        )
    return formatting


styled_df = df.rename(columns=str.lower).style.apply(
    highlight_letter,
    axis='columns'
)
```

The output on your test data looks like this:
[image: screenshot of the output]

**Update**

Here's another way for the case where we have a fixed structure, like first half of columns are letters, and the next one - the corresponding columns of their scores:

```py
half = len(df.columns)//2
score = df.iloc[:, half:]

category_level = np.add(
    score <= 10,
    score <= 20,
    dtype=int     # need this to accumulate integers, not booleans
)

category_formatting = [   
    'background-color: blue',          # default color
    'background-color: lightgreen',    # <=10
    'background-color: yellow',        # <=20
]

formatting = np.choose(category_level, category_formatting)
```

At this point, `formatting` is a `DataFrame` with column names from the second half. To get the right applying, we have to replace column names with their twins from the first half:

```py
formatting.columns = df.columns[:half]
styled_df = df.style.apply(lambda _: formatting, axis=None)
```